# Building an Image Editor with HTML 5 and Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html, canvas

I wanted to build a product customizer similar to http://www.getuncommon.com. But instead of Flash, I will utilize HTML5 canvas and Javascript.

Is there a library which I can use to create and achieve similar editor/product customizer as Uncommon?

I did look at jQuery UI but it is seem more focused on interface than creating my own editor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did something similar to this a while ago.

I used JQuery and [Raphael JS](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/). Raphael uses VML in Internet Explorer and SVG and Canvas in other browsers making it a very good cross-browser compatible option.

A good demo of a project using Raphael can be found [here](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/playground.html).

I used a lot of code from this demo to develop my own tool.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Anymore libraries similar to this?

Comment: @Adam Is there any library to develop editor for my json objects?

Comment: @chaosguru sorry, not sure on that one.

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib try http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/. I have updated the link above :-)

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at [Fabric.js canvas library](http://fabricjs.com/demos/).

We're using it in production for [design editor on printio.ru](http://printio.ru/tees/new)

Answer (score 2):

I used [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com) to create an [E-Card editor](http://ecardcanvas.com/edit). It was a great experience using the library.